# Aligning equations with align

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align, matrices

Imagine I have the following system

```
\begin{align}
    a&=b\\
    abc&=def+1\\
    e&=mc^2-H(x,y,z)
\end{align}
```

[image]

I want to add a first column aligned in a different manner, like so

[image]

is this possible to do with `align`? If not, what good alternative could I use? Note that I want to index each equation separately, so I believe `matrix` wouldn't work.

Comment: The number of `&` needs to be 2x number of alignments minus 1. So ``m & =0: & a & = b \\`` will be the first line

Comment: @daleif That's great! I didn't know it worked like that. Do you know if it is somehow possible to control the spacing between the left-hand column of equations (m's) and the right-hand one?

Comment: The use `alignedat` instead, it needs the number of alignments as a parameter. It makes the dist between alignment columns zero and thus a manual space can be added between them.

Comment: @daleif - Both the standalone `aligned`/`aligned*` and the embeddable `alignedat`/`alignedat*` environments provide ways to control the spacing between the left-hand and right-hand groups of equations.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but this question indicates unfamiliarity with the possibilities provided by the `amsmath` package.  Therefore, reading the user guide for `amsmath` (`texdoc amsldoc`) could be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

You asked in a follow-up comment:

> Do you know if it is somehow possible to control the spacing between the left-hand column of equations (m's) and the right-hand one?

That's actually where the `alignat` and `alignat*` environments very much come into their own. Consider the following three `alignat*{2}` environments:

[image]

The first group shows that, in general, it's *not* a good idea to provide no separation instruction between the left-hand and right-hand equations. The second and third group differ only in where the instruction `\qquad` is placed: it's in row 2 for the middle group, and in row 1 for the third and final group. In practice, one would (should?) place the spacing instruction (here: `\qquad`) in the row for which the spacing is narrowest to begin with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
m&=0{:} &        a&=b\\
m&=1{:} &        abc&=def+1\\
m&=2{:} &        e&=mc^2-H(x,y,z)
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
m&=0{:} &        a&=b\\
m&=1{:} &\qquad  abc&=def+1\\
m&=2{:} &        e&=mc^2-H(x,y,z)
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
m&=0{:} &\qquad  a&=b\\
m&=1{:} &        abc&=def+1\\
m&=2{:} &        e&=mc^2-H(x,y,z)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```